# Applying Intermediate Value Theorem to a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Question: $f(x$) = $x^5-15x^4-10x^2+20$

Prove that the equation $f(x) = 0$ has a real solution with $x \geq 1$.

Idea: Started off by coming up with a boundary $[1,x]$ for some real number $x$. $f(1)=-4$ so is less than zero, then attempted to find an $x$ that gave me a positive result, very quickly came to the conclusion that any number above 1 when inserted into a function gave me a negative number. Pretty sure I could be missing something really simple.
Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you saying "very quickly came to the conclusion that any number above 1 when inserted into a function gave me a negative number"??? May be you have done in hurry/quickly that is why did something wrong... Can you tell me how did you see $f(x)<0$ for every $x\geq 1$??

Comment: Sorry I apologise for the question, I realise i should have spent more time on it.

Comment: There are three real Solutions of the equation $$f(x)=0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(20)$ is positive. So, check again.

Also, for future purposes, to solve such questions, you can easily check the behaviour of a polynomial at large $x$ by just considering the sign of the highest power variable. If it is positive, then $f(x)\to\infty$, and if it is negative, then $f(x)\to-\infty$.

Comment: how did you know that $f(20)$ is positive?

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, could you please elaborate on your comment about finding a large x? I am finding it a bit difficult to comprehend.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik By simple calculation. I got the hint as at large values of $x$, the polynomial is dominated by $x^5 - 15x^4 = x^4(x-15)$. Thus, $x=20$ seemed like a reasonable choice which could give a positive value of f(x), which it did.

Comment: @ViB For large values of x, the value of $f(x)$ is largely dominated by the values of the highest powers of $f(x)$. Here, $f(20) = 796020$, while $20^5 - 15*20^4 = 800000$. So, the value of $f(x)$ is dominated by this term. Lower power terms of f(x) barely affect the value (and thus, more importantly in our case, the sign). Similarly, for larger $x$, as $x^5 - 15*x^4 = x^4(x-15)$, for large $x$, $x-15 \approx x$. Hence, the value (and thus the sign) of $f(x)$ as $x\to\infty$ is determined by $x^5$, the highest power term in $f(x)$

Comment: So to tackle problems like this in the future its best to focus on larger powers of x and simplifying in such a way that we can find a number x that is positive (in this case)?

Comment: @ViB Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f(1)<0$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}=\infty.$

Comment: I do not know any simple proof for $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\infty$.. Can you add one or two lines..

Comment: My answer implies that $f(c)>0$ at some point $c>1$ (why?) and therefore, by IVT, $f(d)=0$ for some $1<d<c.$

Comment: Would you be able to clarify on the reason why this is implied?

Answer (score 0):

> very quickly came to the conclusion that any number above 1 when
>   inserted into a function gave me a negative number

You might want to reconsider this statement. Try $100$ and you'll find $f(100)>0$ and because $f(x)$ is continuous then by the Intermediate Value Theorem you can conclude that somewhere in $[1,100]$ $f(x)=0$

Note: Odd polynomials with a leading positive coefficient will go to $-\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$ and go to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$